# Firefox add-on that tracks webpage load time including DNS retrieve time?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, time, statistics

I used to have this add-on but now I forgot what it's called. Basically it can track any website's load time, DNS seeking time, time from host to javascript execution and HTML rendering, things like that.

Got any suggestions for such an add-on for Firefox? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Firebug's](http://getfirebug.com/) "Net" panel does this.  It gives you timing info for the following:

- DNS lookup
- Connecting
- Queueing
- Waiting for response
- Receiving data
- When the DOMContentLoaded event fires
- When the load event fires

Comment: wow didn't know firebugs can figure out the DNS lookup thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another one worth checking out is [Yahoo's YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) which is an extension that integrates with Firebug