# How to track time spent waiting for webpages to load

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, logging, time-management

I would like to track the amount of time I spend waiting for webpages to load in Firefox or Chrome(ium) in a given time period (1 day for example). I am **NOT** trying to optimize a single page or website, rather I would like to find a way to aggregate the total amount of time I spend waiting for pages to load. Breaking up the data by website/page would be ideal.

Comment: [Firefox add-on that tracks webpage load time including DNS retrieve time?](http://superuser.com/q/89697) shows how to do it for a single page ...

Comment: This would be useful to tell network admins how much of our lives we are wasting waiting for pages to load.